# Linux permissions/owner for nginx's root folder with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, linux, nginx

My nginx's root folder `/usr/share/nginx/html` is owned by root:root but I need to add/edit/delete files with my user `mark`. Also, I'm using PHP with fastcgi (php-fpm) and I need to upload file in a specific directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/userfiles`. My current configuration is like following:

```
sudo groupadd webdev;
sudo usermod -a -G webdev mark;
sudo chown root:webdev /usr/share/nginx/html;
sudo chmod 2775 /usr/share/nginx/html -R;
sudo chgrp -R www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/userfiles;
```

I found out some problems about uploaded files (they are created in `/usr/share/nginx/html/userfiles` correctly, but my user `mark` can't open/edit/delete these files). How can I solve it? Any suggestions for a better configuration?

Comment: `sudo groupadd webupload && sudo usermod -a -G webupload www-data && sudo usermod -a -G webupload mark && sudo chgrp -R webupload /usr/share/nginx/html/userfiles;` ?

Comment: @Siguza thank you but it doesn't work due to permission denied as I can see in php log file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in sharing access to files by having a common group, but the files and directories
you create must belong to the group and also be read/write to the group.

Files created by PHP I assume will be in group www-data, but will probably not have group write permission unless you  change the umask in `/etc/init/php-fpm.conf`. Add a line:

```
umask 0002
```

If your id has www-data amongst its groups, you will be able to edit the file.

If you create a file, it will not be in group www-data, but probably your
own group `mark`. So if you want PHP i.e. www-data to be able to edit that
file you need, by symmetry, to `usermod -a -G mark www-data`, and ensure when you create
files that they are read/write to the group (umask 2 and check or chmod g+w).

Ensure the directory userfiles is rwx to the group www-data, or chmod g+rwx it.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any other suggestions about my configuration to improve security or other things?

Comment: When uploading files be sure to remove all chars but alphanumeric from provided filenames. Never make them executable. Check your limits on max upload file sizes, imposed by php.